# Quick Uninstall/Reinstall of a Custom Module

Tags: installation

I'm working on creating a module and I'm slowly getting familiar with the Field API and what all settings work on various fields and what don't. While I'm doing this, it seems that the only way to update a custom content type is to disable the module, uninstall it, then re-enable it.

Is there an easy way to do this? Right now, it's a somewhat laborious process that requires a handful of clicks to do the same thing over and over. I'm looking for a script or module to handling this very quickly with (ideally) a single click.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Solution 1. Devel + Drush:**

You can use [devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) drush command for module re-installation with all the module dependencies:

```
drush devel-reinstall modulename
```

There is also alias for this command

```
drush dre modulename
```

**Solution 2. Drush:**

This is something that I would typically use [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) for

```
drush pm-disable mymodule
drush pm-uninstall mymodule
drush pm-enable mymodule
```

You could also use it to define your own custom commands to combine these into a single command.

Comment: You are a life saver. You (and drush) have no doubt saved me hours (eventually).

Comment: drush devel-reinstall modulename

Comment: drush devel-reinstall modulename -y 

The -y means you don't have to keep entering y to continue.

Comment: If you have devel (you should), run 
`drush dre mymodule`

Comment: the most efficient command is `drush dre MODULENAME -y`

Answer (score 8):

If you don't have shell access the [Devel module](https://drupal.org/project/devel) provides such functionality. Install it and visit *mysite.com/devel/reinstall*.

Comment: oh this indeed reinstalls a module, but what about updating a custom module as you would do with the "install new module" button and then uploading a zipped version? :/ I am in a situation where the drupal site is on a cloud platform, and I don't have the luxury of drush / file system access.

Answer (score -2):

For those of you that want a script that does the devel command without the devel:
https://github.com/nategd/drupal_module_restart